# Are these arguments -- in philosophy of mind?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, artificial-intelligence, qualia, animals

Do any of these arguments [epiphanies] exist in the philosophy of mind?

1. Consciousness is a complex structure, and it is unlikely to be realizable in just any structure, else anything big enough would be conscious, and binary data is very different from the brain: so AI without wet brains is silly. **An argument that the complexity of a structure isn't enough and then disanalogy with non biological complex structures.**
2. A patch of red exists without consciousness of it, and is red, what the only difference is, is that "I", or something else, *has* that experience, and that is because consciousness is *about* its object, that I can reflect on qualia: but the same isn't true of animal life. **An explanation of qualia in terms of higher-order conscious intentionality**.
3. Qualia depend upon me having them, which is the self identity of me: but then as I can unconsciously experience things that don't exist, so "I" am, in part, already an experience of nothing. **Saying that I am just my qualia, and so exist when they don't have any Being, e.g. when asleep**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102255/discussion-on-question-by-another-name-are-these-arguments-in-philosophy-of-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, they have all been made in some way or other (insofar as I can make sense of them):

Your 1. is reminiscent of the [China brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_brain) thought experiment, and other similar objections to functionalism about qualia. The [Chinese room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room) thought experiment is also tangentially related.

Your 2. is explored in so-called [higher-order theories of consciousness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness-higher/), although many of their proponents would agree that many animals are capable of the relevant higher-order mental states.

Your 3. is a bit harder for me to assess, because its formulation is less clear. It reminds me of so-called [psychological-continuity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-personal/#PsyApp) views on personal identity. Note that personal identity is a slightly different topic from the one your first two arguments deal with, which is the metaphysics of consciousness.

Comment: i was already kinda aware of all that, but thanks, don't think i'll get a better answer